# Wireshask - Get rtmp url from this stream?

Tags: http, stream, web-crawler, rtmp, wireshark

I have been use to listen to a radio for quite a long time from WMP. But then they changed their structure and move to FMS server, which stream RTMP. I can only listen from their website. As much as posible I could like to get the RTMP url so that I could fire up my VLC.

http://vov.vn/RadioPlayer.aspx?c=vov3

This is the player, the channel is VOV3.

I try to use wireshark but I couldn't get any URL, host or request URI from it.

Inspect into the stream packets, it's all MP3, and the port is 8080 (http-alt). IP is 123.30.50.46

However there are several interesting packets from the capture:

```
0080  00 07 5f 72 65 73 75 6c  74 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00   .._resul t.?.....
0090  00 00 03 00 06 66 6d 73  56 65 72 02 00 0e 46 4d   .....fms Ver...FM
00a0  53 2f 34 2c 30 2c 33 2c  34 30 31 30 00 0c 63 61   S/4,0,3, 4010..ca
00b0  70 61 62 69 6c 69 74 69  65 73 00 40 6f e0 00 00   pabiliti es.@o...
00c0  00 00 00 00 04 6d 6f 64  65 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00   .....mod e.?.....
00d0  00 00 00 00 09 03 00 05  6c 65 76 65 6c 02 00 06   ........ level...
00e0  73 74 61 74 75 73 00 04  63 6f 64 65 02 00 1d 4e   status.. code...N
00f0  65 74 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63  74 69 6f 6e 2e 43 6f 6e   etConnec tion.Con
0100  6e 65 63 74 2e 53 75 63  63 65 73 73 00 0b 64 65   nect.Suc cess..de
0110  73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f  6e 02 00 15 43 6f 6e 6e   scriptio n...Conn
0120  65 63 74 69 6f 6e 20 73  75 63 63 65 65 64 65 64   ection s ucceeded
0130  2e 00 0e 6f 62 6a 65 63  74 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e   ...objec tEncodin
0140  67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 04 64 61 74 61   g....... ....data
0150  08 00 00 00 00 00 07 76  65 72 73 69 6f 6e 02 00   .......v ersion..
0160  0a 34 2c 30 2c 33 2c 34  30 31 30 00 00 09 00 00   .4,0,3,4 010.....
```

---

```
0070  02 00 08 6f 6e 53 74 61  74 75 73 00 00 00 00 00   ...onSta tus.....
0080  00 00 00 00 05 03 00 05  6c 65 76 65 6c 02 00 06   ........ level...
0090  73 74 61 74 75 73 00 04  63 6f 64 65 02 00 14 4e   status.. code...N
00a0  65 74 53 74 72 65 61 6d  2e 50 6c 61 79 2e 52 65   etStream .Play.Re
00b0  73 65 74 00 0b 64 65 73  63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e   set..des cription
00c0  02 00 1b 50 6c 61 79 69  6e 67 20 61 6e 64 20 72   ...Playi ng and r
00d0  65 73 65 74 74 69 6e 67  20 76 6f 76 33 2e 00 07   esetting  vov3...
00e0  64 65 74 61 69 6c 73 02  00 04 76 6f 76 33 00 08   details. ..vov3..
00f0  63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 64  02 00 08 70 41 41 37 41   clientid ...pAA7A
```

---

```
0050  08 6f 6e 53 74 61 74 75  73 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .onStatu s.......
0060  00 00 05 03 00 05 6c 65  76 65 6c 02 00 06 73 74   ......le vel...st
0070  61 74 75 73 00 04 63 6f  64 65 02 00 14 4e 65 74   atus..co de...Net
0080  53 74 72 65 61 6d 2e 50  6c 61 79 2e 53 74 61 72   Stream.P lay.Star
0090  74 00 0b 64 65 73 63 72  69 70 74 69 6f 6e 02 00   t..descr iption..
00a0  15 53 74 61 72 74 65 64  20 70 6c 61 79 69 6e 67   .Started  playing
00b0  20 76 6f 76 33 2e 00 07  64 65 74 61 69 6c 73 02    vov3... details.
00c0  00 04 76 6f 76 33 00 08  63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 64   ..vov3.. clientid
00d0  02 00 08 70 41 41 37 41  52 44 41 00 00 09 04 00   ...pAA7A RDA.....
00e0  00 00 00 00 18 12 01 00  00 00 02 00 11 7c 52 74   ........ .....|Rt
00f0  6d 70 53 61 6d 70 6c 65  41 63 63 65 73 73 01 00   mpSample Access..
0100  01 00 04 00 00 00 00 01  44 12 01 00 00 00 02 00   ........ D.......
0110  0a 6f 6e 4d 65 74 61 44  61 74 61 03 00 06 61 75   .onMetaD ata...au
0120  74 68 6f 72 02 00 00 00  09 63 6f 70 79 72 69 67   thor.... .copyrig
0130  68 74 02 00 00 00 0b 64  65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69   ht.....d escripti
0140  6f 6e 02 00 00 00 08 6b  65 79 77 6f 72 64 73 02   on.....k eywords.
0150  00 00 00 06 72 61 74 69  6e 67 02 00 00 00 05 74   ....rati ng.....t
0160  69 74 6c 65 02 00 00 00  0a 70 72 65 73 65 74 6e   itle.... .presetn
0170  61 6d 65 02 00 06 43 75  73 74 6f 6d 00 0c 63 72   ame...Cu stom..cr
0180  65 61 74 69 6f 6e 64 61  74 65 02 00 19 54 68 75   eationda te...Thu
0190  20 41 75 67 20 32 35 20  31 38 3a 32 34 3a 31 33    Aug 25  18:24:13
01a0  20 32 30 31 31 0a 00 0b  61 75 64 69 6f 64 65 76    2011... audiodev
01b0  69 63 65 02 00 1f 53 6f  75 6e 64 20 42 6c 61 73   ice...So und Blas
01c0  74 65 72 20 58 2d 46 69  20 58 74 72 65 6d 65 20   ter X-Fi  Xtreme 
01d0  41 75 64 69 6f 00 0f 61  75 64 69 6f 73 61 6d 70   Audio..a udiosamp
01e0  6c 65 72 61 74 65 00 40  e5 88 80 00 00 00 00 00   lerate.@ ........
01f0  0d 61 75 64 69 6f 63 68  61 6e 6e 65 6c 73 00 40   .audioch annels.@
0200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  10 61 75 64 69 6f 69 6e   ........ .audioin
0210  70 75 74 76 6f 6c 75 6d  65 00 40 51 40 00 00 00   putvolum e.@Q@...
0220  00 00 00 0c 61 75 64 69  6f 63 6f 64 65 63 69 64   ....audi ocodecid
0230  02 00 04 2e 6d 70 33 00  0d 61 75 64 69 6f 64 61   ....mp3. .audioda
0240  74 61 72 61 74 65 00 40  60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   tarate.@ `.......
```

Could someone be able to get the URL from this stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just been on a huge mission round the houses with Wireshark and eventually reached a dead end because it never does a DNS lookup for the RTMP stream. Then I realised that it must therefore be hard-coded with an IP address. If you view the source on the page you will find this...

```
so.addParam('flashvars','&file=vov3.flv&streamer=rtmp://123.30.50.46:8080/live&skin=/Images/modieus.swf&autostart=true');
```

So I guess the URL would be

```
rtmp://123.30.50.46:8080/live/vov3.flv
```

I can't get it to work in my VLC but I think that is a problem with my VLC rather than the URL.

If you need any more info about the the stream or generally want to have a play, [check this out](http://all-streaming-media.com/record-video-stream/rtmpdump-freeware-console-RTMP-downloading-application.htm).

Comment: ffmpeg now does rtmp, so mplayer, being based on ffmpeg, will do rtmp streams unless they are encrypted (rtmpe). It won't work with all streams though.